# Dumpbin output ,meaning?

Tags: visual-c++, exe, coff, dumpbin

If I do something like this:

```
dumpbin myexe.exe
```

I got output similar to:

```
Dump of file myexe.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

Summary

      21000 .data
       1000 .gfids
     3C9000 .rdata
      4F000 .reloc
      B4000 .rsrc
     325000 .text
       1000 .tls
```

Second column (.data, .gfids, .rdata...) represents section name.
But what is first column? Section size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This value is actually the *aligned* section size.

If you do `dumpbin /headers myexe.exe`, you will get a more verbose output. For example, `dumpbin C:\Windows\explorer.exe` on my system produces:

```
Dump of file c:\Windows\explorer.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

Summary

    4000 .data
    1000 .didat
    1000 .imrsiv
   18000 .pdata
   7B000 .rdata
    6000 .reloc
  1EA000 .rsrc
  1C5000 .text
```

`dumpbin /headers C:\Windows\explorer.exe`, contains the output for the `.text` section as follows (... = lines omitted):

```
...
SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
  1C4737 virtual size
    1000 virtual address (0000000140001000 to 00000001401C5736)
  1C4800 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 001C4BFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read
...
```

It also gives `1000 section alignment` in the `OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES` section.

As you can see, the size of the `.text` section is actually `1C4737`, when aligned, it becomes `1C5000`, as reported in the `/summary` (which is the default option for dumpbin).